# Can I use Sunflower oil to make soap?

Tags: home-experiment, fats

When reading about making glycerine soap, the recipes suggested to melt animal fat and mix it with $\ce{NaOH}$.

Could I use Sunflower oil instead? Or a olive oil for nice flavor? Is heating necessary in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any triglyceride, but the touch, the firmness, the cleaning effectiveness of the resulting soap will be different. Soaps also can go rancid just like their corresponding fat/oil. DIY soapmakers generally mix oil or use specifically selected ones. Coconut oil, castor oil, olive oil, animal fats are generally popular.
Without the intent to advertise any specific site:
http://www.lovinsoap.com/oils-chart/

Olive oil is actually a pretty common component, and you can buy olive oil based soaps even is shops. Flavor? If you do it well, most probably not much remains.

Heating is generally necessarily, saponification is a slow reaction and most home-made soap is not fully reacted (containing lot of NaOH).

Note on safety:
Many people make soap at home, because it is "more natural/organic" just following some youtube videos without knowing much about lab work or chemistry. Using your own blender, doing in your kitchen or using your own kitchenware is a very bad idea. NaOH can make you blind, so do not ignore the "wear googles!" signs. Also just mixing everything up in a highly corrosive mixture contains or not remains of NaOH or produce all kind of unknown byproducts then putting everything on your skin may not the healthiest choice of living.

Comment: Can I calculate the proper amounts of oil and sodium hydroxide to get (almost) 100% reaction (no oil or lye). But in fact, my original plan was to make glycerine and nitrate it, so it's not really healthiness I'm looking for.

Comment: Sure, you can, but it will be no exact. Glycerine and nitrate.. Not much to do with the topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any triglyceride to make soap.  The process is called saponification.  In this process fatty acid molecules are cleaved from glycerol (glycerine).  In order for the reaction to proceed it is heated.  Regardless of the fatty acid source, the soap will probably not taste very good.